# Ajax Script for the Edit function not Displaying the saved Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-8

The issue when hitting the Edit icon under my action column in my data tables, the saved data was not displayed as expected, I figured this was only happening  for file input type, for text input type it works properly

In Blade file

Add Form

```
<form class="form" id="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required>
    file<input type="file" class="form-control" name="path" required>
</form>
```

Update form

```
<form class="form" id="Update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Name<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id= "editname"  required>
        file<input type="file" class="form-control" name="path" id= "editpath" required>
    </form>
```

In my data tables to display for the user to hit the Edit icon under my Action Column

```
<div class="responsive">
     <table id="myFiles">
        <thead>
           <tr>
                 <th>File</th>
                  <th>Action</th>

                   </tr>
                       </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           @foreach($files as $f)
                              <tr>
                                <td><a href="{{ asset($f->path) }}">{{ $f->name }}</a></td>
                                                    
                               <td>
                                 <div class="topButtons">
                                   <form class="formEditDataF">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="upload_id" value="{{ $f->id }}">
                                 <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="bx bx-edit-alt font-medium-1"></i></button>
                                  </form>
                              </div>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     @endforeach
                  </tbody>
         </table>
     </div> `
```

For my Script file, For **Edit**

```
$('#myFiles').on('submit', '.formEditDataF', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{ route('getfile') }}",
            processData:false,
            data: formData
        }).done(function(response) {
            $('#edit_file_id').val(response.id);
            $('#editname').val(response.name);
            $('#editpath').val(response.path);


            $('#myModal2').modal('show');
    
        }).fail(function(data) {
            swal({
                type: "error",
                title: "Oops. An Error Occured",
                text: "Please try again"
            });
        });
    });
```

Script for Update

in my Controller

```
 public function getFile(Request $request) {
    $data = DB::table('file.file')->where([['id', $request->file_id]])->first();
 
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HTML` is declared `id= editpath` but was called `$('#edit_path')` in your JS.
The same goes for `id="editname"` and `$('#edit_name')`.

It should be `id="editpath"` and `$('#editpath')` and so on.

EDIT:
what went wrong:

```
$('#editpath').val(response.path);
```

you're directly setting the value of the `file input` which is **not allowed**. to display the image, you need another element for that.

Check out the snippet below. you could do something like this.

```js
image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/102396/1635865698-headsways.png'; //replace with with your image path
$(image).attr('id', 'image');
$(image).attr('height', '200px');
$(image).attr('width', '200px');

image.onload = function() {
    $('#img-cont').append(image);
}

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="img-cont"></div>

FILE<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this)">
```

Comment: @makoz still some problems `id "editname"`

Comment: have updated my post - can you check the script file and also code on data tables for edit - how can it accepts a file type- for input type text - it works fine - only when i change the input type to file - my "Edit" functionality doesn't work -

Comment: @makoz what does `response()->json($data);` look like? does it return image blob or just file path?

Comment: @makoz if it returns file path you can add new html element to display the image. check this out https://jsfiddle.net/wLvah3p2/

Comment: @tension - once user hit the save button, a pop-up message says ,data is saved successfully, if not, then throw an error message

Comment: @tension - for add and delete functionality is working, the issue when user hit the Edit button, the saved file name and path was not showing, and FYI, I want to stick and use the same method of that script, what did I miss on that script that when hit the edit button the save data was not displayed ..

Comment: @makoz can you do a `console.log(response)` can you show me the response?

Comment: where to place the console.log code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242586/discussion-between-makoz-and-tenshi).